# Google Speech API - possible to get phonemic transcript?

Tags: c#, api, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

Does anyone know a way to get a phonemic transcript of the recognized speech output obtained from Google Cloud Speech to Text API?

I am able to get a normal (graphemic) list of alternatives with confidences but I am interested in getting the output at the phone level in a similar way as Microsoft Speech does by using WordUnit.Pronunciation.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. API does not have such feature.